# Ошибка в base64 (Last unit does not have enough valid bits)

Tags: java, строки, utf-8, base64

Делаю не большую библиотеку RSA для себя на джаве.
У меня есть 2 метода "byteToString" и "stringToByte", это нужно что-бы передать байты в строки.
Но я столкнулся с ошибкой когда со строки переделываю в байты.

```
public static byte[] stringToByte(String str) {
    return Base64.getDecoder().decode(str);
}

public static String byteToString(byte[] b) {
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(b);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "Hello";
    System.out.println(KeyUtils.stringToByte(text));
}
```

[image: Ошибка]

Я использую стандартную библиотеку Base64(ISO_8859_1) 
Но также я пытался сделать вот так:

```
public static byte[] stringToByte(String str) {
    return str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}

public static String byteToString(byte[] b) {
    return new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "Hello";
    System.out.println(KeyUtils.stringToByte(text));
}
```

На мае удивления здесь нет ошибки.
НО самая проблема в том, что когда я хочу зашифрование байты с помощи РСА переделать в строку. У меня получается это.

```
NàƒSûšêõ%á1+á®(÷õü‡5XUà:£•¹µú=*azë÷æ^‹R¬Ï"êÿo•9"‡D¢F’Eñe«£Î¹
mÆûäx´GÒ»å~‡R@”Ië=éCâùò2(î·ÄË>µZ¹Ý8:1-½b*µÙõÑ¾Þþ2òq¡¸TÞ.±¹ÐI±Ø²µw£Z‡Ü;ŽIŽ/ìG‹nËg+IÛ>ÉZr…z#[ã|Ô
```

А хотелось бы увидеть такое

```
K/XUn9wYvKKehQBiV370cXXF44TM8UoGI+tWbW22koOqHOIzYEB71wAP2jiYuC0x0O08I20HNt+wdFZKdUNXaeDSIxWivrKUZMRS9nglY2d+hBGw+mBW2QVwk93crq5TtOZxZb2SsL26FH5f/SBs8q3eFCC9F7OMCpJRWPaH1E4=
```

Что посоветуете?

Comment: у тебя код что-то не правильный приведен stringToByte имеет тип результата byte[], а в теле у тебя возвращается строка (new String(...)), ты код не перепутал в теле функций? аналогично вторая функция.

Comment: Да, извините перепутал код местами когда вставлял его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь декодировать "Hello" из base64, но эта строка не является base64-encoded строкой.

> ```
> Функция | Вход     | Выход
> ________|__________|________
> decode  | SGVsbG8= | Hello
> encode  | Hello    | SGVsbG8=
> decode  | Hellow== | �e� (0x1de965a3)
> ```

---

Давайте попробуем вручную закодировать и раскодировать 'Hello' в/из **Base64**:

```
'Hello'
'H' 0100 1000
'e' 0110 0101
'l' 0110 1100
'l' 0110 1100
'o' 0110 1111
```

**Encode**:

- извлекаем по 6 бит из входного потока дополняем ведущими нулями
- маппим на base64 алфавит `[A-Za-z0-9+/]`

```
00 0100 10 S
00 00 0110 G
00 0101 01 V
00 10 1100 s
00 0110 11 b
00 00 0110 G
00 1111 .. 8= ("=" — признак нехватки 2х бит, 
                     если бы тут не хватало 4х бит, мы бы добавили "==")
```

**Decode**:

- Маппим base64 текст в байты по алфавиту `[A-Za-z0-9+/]`
- игнорируя первые 2 нулевых бита собираем байты из потока битов

```
'H' 00 0001 11
'e' 00 01 1110
'l' 00 1001 01
'l' 00 10 0101
'o' 00 1010 00 

 0001 1101 0x1D
 1110 1001 0xE9
 0110 0101 0x65
 1010 00?? 0xA? <- Проблема (Last unit does not have enough valid bits)
                            (На последний блок не хватило бит)
```

---

Следующий вызов должен работать корректно:

```
System.out.println(new String(stringToByte(byteToString("Hello".getBytes()))));
```

---

```
import java.util.Base64;


public class Main
{
    public static String encode(byte[] bytes) {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
    }
    public static String encodeWithoutPadding(byte[] bytes) {
      return Base64.getEncoder()
                   .withoutPadding()
                   .encodeToString(bytes);
    }
    public static byte[] decode(String s) {
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Hello, World!";
        String encoded = encodeWithoutPadding(s.getBytes());
        String decoded = new String(decode(encoded));
        System.out.println(encoded);
        System.out.println(decoded);
    }
}
```

Comment: Извините я перепутал код местами, когда просил о помощи.
Я питаюсь сделать со строки байты, но появляется ошибка выше.
`System.out.println(Base64.getDecoder().decode("Hello"));`

Comment: Ну, таки мой ответ ровно про decode("Hello"), читайте с самого начала

Comment: Как говорил товарищ Матроскин: «Чтобы decode что-нибудь ненужное, сначала нужно encode что-нибудь ненужное» =)

Comment: @Gru2303, добавил детальное объяснение процесса возникновения ошибки

Comment: Да) все работает. Спасибо